# How can I upload a JSONL file to write queries on in Valentina Studio?

Tags: jsonlines, valentina-studio

How can I upload a JSONL file to Valentina Studio to write SQL queries on?

I tried to load dump to a database, but it is not working.

Comment: Can you provide more info like which database (MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, ... ) are you using, as sample of a jsonl file, and a sample of a SQL query you want to run ?   Currently the question if [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it's not about programming, it's just about using some tool. 